# NSFetchedResultsController's didChangeSection method not being called (Wrong)

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

My NSFetchedResultsController's didChangeSection method not being called. I have searched the web, and found that may be use transient property for sectionNameKeyPath will caused this problem.  From here:["didChangeSection:" NSfetchedResultsController delegate method not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637744/didchangesection-nsfetchedresultscontroller-delegate-method-not-being-called)

Is this really because of transient property? And how to get didChangeSection be called when use transient property for sectionNameKeyPath? I used viewForHeaderInSection to customize the section header, how to let it update without didChangeSection method?

Now I use `[self.tableView reloadDate]` in `viewWillAppear`, but I feel it a little slow after added or deleted an item, although it may be 0.5 seconds.

My fetchedResultsController's setup was like the DateSectionTitles, a sample of Apple:http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html

That sample is simple only contain `- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController` in fetch result controller part. I added some tableview related method:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
```

Only `- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type` not being called.

I used date as section title, but need update section header's other part, that is a sum of row items's amount.

Update: I am wrong. It is being called. I thought insert a cell (not new section), and the didChangeSection should be called and update my customized section header. But didChangeSection only being called for insert of delete a section. Just use [self.tableView reloadDate], and the section header will be update for cell change.

I tried to put the [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL] in front position of modal view's close view method, and the view will close quickly and can see the cell inserting animation.

Comment: You *can* use a transient property for sectionNameKeyPath. But you must use persistent properties as keys for the sort descriptors. And the first sort descriptor must generate the same ordering as the sectionNameKeyPath. - If this sounds too complicated: Show your setup of the fetched results controller, perhaps someone can help.

Comment: Yes, I use a transient property for sectionNameKeyPath. Like the apple's sample DateSectionTitles, and the sort descriptor is persistent properties and same order.

Comment: Perhaps you can show the creation code of the fetched results controller, and also your implementation of sectionNameKeyPath.

Comment: Your implementation of viewForHeaderInSection would also be interesting to reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is difficult to help if you don't provide more information :-)

Comment: Thank you. But I am now dealing with other things. Just use [self.tableView reloadData] and now not feeling slow. I forget did something to it.